# How can I get this title page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

[image: another half][image: doc format]

I want my university title page but I wonder if can I get this. As I was trying a lot with many classes but I am not getting the correct format. Could someone help me to get this? I don't know how to get the correct format exactly the same as the requirement. So I included in tags. I hope I get an excuse for this.

```
\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
       \else\newpage\fi}
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn\else\newpage\fi}

\newenvironment{custom}{}

%define title page layout
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\pagenumbering{roman} % Sasa Tomic
\setcounter{page}{0}  % Sasa Tomic
\begin{alwayssingle}
    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\relax}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
%  \null\vfill
  \begin{center}
   \begin{flushleft} { \Large {\bfseries {\@university}} \par} \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushleft} {{\Large \@collegeordept} \par} \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushleft} {{\Large Author: \@author} \par} \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushleft} {{\Large E-mail address: sagh0901@student.miun.se} \par}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushleft} {{\Large Study programme: Msc Computer Science} \par}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushleft} {{\Large Examiner: Blah Blah} \par} \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushleft} {{\Large Tutors: Andreas Nordgren, email} \par}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushleft} {{\Large Scope: ??? words inclusive of appendices} \par}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushleft} {{\Large Date: \@degreedate} \par} \end{flushleft} 
    {\large \ {{\@crest} \par} \vspace*{25mm}}
     {\large {M.Sc. Thesis within Computer Engineering 30hp points} \par}
      { \Large {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
      {\normalsize {Subtitle} \par}
      {\Huge {\@author} \par}
  \end{center}

\end{alwayssingle}}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more information, e.g., about font sizes, font weight (normal, bold?), vertical distance between individual lines (single- or other spacing?) and between the left-aligned and centered blocks, overall page size (A4? US letter? some other size?) and size of type block (text height and width?). Without this additional information, it's going to be impossible to give adequate recommendations.

Comment: Plus what you have tried so far would be helpful

Comment: Use the [`titlepage`](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#titlepage) environment to create the title with simple commands. This will be less tedious than redefining the `\maketitle` command.

Answer (score 7):

As already remarked in my comment, you only need the `titlepage` enviroment to create a title on your own.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{isodate}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \sffamily
    \raggedright
    \textbf{University}\\
    The Department of Information Technology and Media (ITM)\\
    Author: [Author's Name]\\
    E-Mail address: [Author's E-Mail address]\\
    Study programme: [Study programme, credit points]\\
    Examiner: [Dr. Anders Andersson, e-mail address]\\
    Tutors: [Bertil Bertilsson, organiston X, e-mail address]\\
    Scope: 6630 words inclusive of appendices\\
    Date: \isodate{\today}

    \centering
    \vfill
    [Place for Illustration]
    \vfill
    \large
    [B.Sc. Thesis / M.Sc. Thesis / project report\\
    within Computer Engineering / Electrical Engineering\\
    A/B/C/D, course, X points]\\[\bigskipamount]
    \huge
    [Title]\\
    \large
    [Subtitle]\\[\bigskipamount]
    \huge
    [Author's Name]
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You haven't exactly provided a lot of information on the titlepage's specifications, other than the text that has to be be featured. Hence, the following code can only be regarded as a first approximation to what you need.

```
\documentclass[a4]{report}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5in,vmargin=1.25in]{geometry}

\newenvironment{specialtitlepage}{%
   \clearpage % make sure we start on a new page
   \sffamily
   \obeylines
   }{\thispagestyle{empty}
   \clearpage} % make sure to end page at end of env.

\begin{document}
\begin{specialtitlepage}
\textbf{\large University}
The Department of Information Technology and Media (ITM)
Author: [xyz]
Email address: [xyz]
Study programme: [xyz,  credit points]
Examiner: [xyz, email address]
Tutor: [name, organization, email address]
Scope: [xyz]
Date: [xyz]

\vspace{4cm}
\begin{center}
[Place for illustration]
\includegraphics{something.pdf}
\end{center}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{center}
[B.Sc. degree, etc
within Computer Engineering, etc
... X points]

\vspace{1.5cm}
{\Large\textbf{Title}}
Subtitle

\vspace{0.5cm}
{\Large\textbf{Author's Name}}
\end{center}

\end{specialtitlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]